# Is there a reduced ring with exactly $3$ idempotents?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, idempotents

Let $R$ be a [reduced ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduced_ring) (let's assume with identity, although not necessarily commutative).

> Is it possible for $R$ to have exactly 3 idempotent elements? If so, what would be an example?

I know that the idempotents of a reduced ring commute with everything in the ring. This implies that the product of two idempotents is idempotent. But, alas, I don't see how this would help. (After all, if $0$ and $1$ and $u$ are the only idempotents, we can take products of these elements but we don't get anything new.)

---

**Edit:** I see now that it is impossible for $R$ to have exactly $3$ idempotents. (Thank you to the commentors for your insight!) I am still, however, interesting in doing further investigation on the structure of reduced rings. I have now posted a more general follow-up question [Can a reduced ring have (# idempotents) $\in 3 \mathbb{Z}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3457691/can-a-reduced-ring-have-idempotents-in-3-mathbbz?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: No, because idempotents come in orthogonal pairs: if $e$ is an idempotent, $1-e$ is too, and $e(1-e)=0$.

Comment: @Bernard I understand now. Thank you so much!

Comment: In addition, you need that  if $e$ is idempotent, then $e\neq 1-e.$ That is not hard to show.

Comment: @Bernard I think this would imply that there have to be an even number of idempotents (assuming there are not infinitely many). Is that right?

Comment: Yes , at least in the commutative case.

Comment: @Bernard Why would the ring need to be commutative? I mean, isn't the commutativity of each idempotent enough?

Comment: @Pascal'sWager You don't even need reducedness. They come in pairs even if they aren't central.  Of course, the central ones come in (central) pairs too.

Comment: I think so, I'm not too sure, because I'm not a noncommutativist (or should I say I'm commuting? :) and I'm wondering whether  noncommuting people will pull out of their sleeve.

Answer (score 2):

No.

Assume $\{0,1,e\}$ are the only idempotents. (All distinct).

By Bernard's comment, $1-e$ is idempotent. We can't have $1-e=0$, otherwise $e=1$. We can't have $1-e=1$, otherwise $e=0$. So we must have $e=1-e$. So $e^2=e-e^2=0$. Since $e^2=0$ and our ring is a reduced ring, we must have $e=0$, a contradiction.

Comment: Note that we don't need $R$ to be reduced: $1 - e = e$ implies $2e = 1$. In particular, $e$ is a unit. This gives a contradiction to $e^2 = 0$. (Since $R$ cannot be the zero ring.)